# Mover posición de elemento al pulsar una tecla

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

Estoy trabajando con C# y me gustaría saber cómo puedo hacer para que un `PictureBox` se mueva con algún botón del teclado. Por ejemplo, con el botón Z y X que vaya para arriba o para abajo respectivamente. ¿Y se podría hacer con dos `PictureBox` diferentes?

Éste es mi código:

```
private void pictureBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode  == Keys.Z) {
        PictureBox1.top -= 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

El evento de teclado no puedes asignarlo al propio control ya que este no tendrá el foco, podrías usar el

[ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Si vas a usar dos `PictureBox` podrías presionar con el ratón para seleccionarlo y después con las teclas lo mueves.

```
public class Form1 : Form1{

    public void Form1_Load(...)
    {
        picturebox1.Click += picturebox_Click;
        picturebox2.Click += picturebox_Click;
    }

}

private PictureBox picSelected = null;

public void picturebox_Click(object sender, ...)
{
    picSelected = (PictureBox)sender;
}

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys keyData)
{
    if(picSelected == null)
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    switch (keyData)
    {
        case Keys.Z:
            picSelected.Top += 10;
            break;

        case Keys.X:
            picSelected.Top -= 10;
            break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

La asociación del evento de selección de los `PictureBox` si lo realizas desde el diseñador no hace falta que lo pongas en el Load del `form`.

La idea es que detectes las teclas globales del `form` y lo puedas mover sumando o restando un valor al Top del control.

Answer (score 0):

*Este código, permite mover los controles por el form en las cuatro direcciones, desbloqueándolos previamente, usando la combinación de teclas (Ctrl+M), y fijar las posiciones (pulsando Enter) sin interferir / pudiendo hacer click en los controles y seguidamente usar las teclas : para otros fines o desempeños, evitando mover los controles sin querer.*

Puede mover cualquier grupo valido* de controles, añadiéndolos a la lista lisControls. Recuerde Activar el evento KeyDown en el Form en que vayan a moverse los controles.

En tiempo de ejecución, pulse Control+M, entonces se resalta de color cyan claro (color de fondo del control) el control que se puede mover.

Muévalo con las teclas : A - Arriba, Z - Abajo, O - Izquierda, P - Derecha.

- Si no desea mover más controles, pulse Enter y quedarán fijadas de nuevo las posiciones.
- Si desea mover otro control, pulse Control+M e irá resaltandose el siguiente control en la lista de controles lisControls.

**(*)** No use este código con controles que no tengan la propiedad BackColor. Para su correcto funcionamiento el Form en que se muevan los controles debe tener el focus.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace controlMover
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    internal List<Control> lisControls = new List<Control>();
    internal Color prevColor; 
    internal int ind = -1;
    internal Control unControl;

    public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

    internal void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        unControl = new PictureBox()
            {
            Name = "pictureBox1",
            Location = new Point(100, 100),
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            };

        this.Controls.Add(unControl);
        lisControls.Add(unControl);

        unControl = new PictureBox()
           {
            Name = "pictureBox2",
            Location = new Point(350, 100),
            Size = new Size(200, 200),
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
           };
        this.Controls.Add(unControl);
        lisControls.Add(unControl);
    }

    private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.M)
        {
            if (ind >= 0)
                lisControls[ind].BackColor = prevColor;

            if (ind < lisControls.Count - 1)
            {
                ind++;
                prevColor = lisControls[ind].BackColor;
                lisControls[ind].BackColor = Color.Azure;
            }
            else
                ind = -1;
        }

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
            if (ind >= 0)
                lisControls[ind].BackColor = prevColor;
            ind = -1;
            }

        if (ind == -1) return;

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            ind = 0;
            return;
        }

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.A:
                lisControls[ind].Location = new Point(lisControls[ind].Location.X, lisControls[ind].Location.Y - 5);
                break;
            case Keys.Z:
                lisControls[ind].Location = new Point(lisControls[ind].Location.X, lisControls[ind].Location.Y + 5);
                break;
            case Keys.O:
                lisControls[ind].Location = new Point(lisControls[ind].Location.X - 5, lisControls[ind].Location.Y);
                break;
            case Keys.P:
                lisControls[ind].Location = new Point(lisControls[ind].Location.X + 5, lisControls[ind].Location.Y);
                break;
        };
      Refresh();
    }
  }
}
```